# How do you set a CodeIgniter radio button, before it's in the $_POST?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So in the CodeIgniter form helper, (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html) you have this function:

`set_radio()`

Permits you to display radio buttons in the state they were submitted. 
This function is identical to the set_checkbox() function above.

```
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '1', TRUE); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" <?php echo set_radio('myradio', '2'); ?> />
```

The problem is that I already have information BEFORE I present the form. As I understand it, this `set_radio()` function uses the data in the POST action to set the value when the form validation fails, and needs to be redone.

Does that make sense?

So if I haven't done the first POST yet, the `set_radio()` doesn't have any data to use to pre-set the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always modify `$_POST` variable, like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['myradio'])) {
    $_POST['myradio'] = $myDefaultValue;
}
```

Do this before you start working with form helper and you should be fine.