# Setting $_POST in CodeIgniter overrides form validation..?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

So in this post [How do you set a CodeIgniter radio button, before it's in the $_POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572943/how-do-you-set-a-codeigniter-radio-button-before-its-in-the-post) TwiStar explained how to modify the $_POST variable, which is great... except that it seems to then override the CodeIgniter form validation functions.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {...}
```

It is probably due to my design... I have some data that I use to pre-populate my form, which I present to the user to review and modify if they wish. The pre-population (unfortunately, in this case) provides exactly the data for the form validation.

So I'm guessing that CodeIgniter's `form_validation->run()` is true when the $_POST contains the right content, which means that my form validation is right before I even start.

If I leave out one of the pre-populated values, I get a crappy user experience.

How can I handle this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem seemed to be more of a design and flow.

The problem: 
Wanting to pre-populate a form with database values, and then allow the user to modify them, and submitting them through a form validation.

The solution:

- In the controller I did not attempt to modify the $_POST values with `if (!isset($_POST['myradio'])) {...}`
- In the form, I did make use of the `set_radio()` function, specifically the third parameter about default values.

The HTML is

```
<input type="radio" name="target" value="direct" <?php echo set_radio('target', "direct", ($data['target'] === 'direct' ? TRUE : " ") ); ?> />
```